# onload event(window.close) is not working in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a problem. `window.close` is working in `UIWebView` (Pop-up), but only not working when in `onload` event.

My Javascript for overriding is:

```
window.close = function () {
    window.location.assign(window.location + '(back)');
};
```

This web page is closed normally.

```
<a href="#none" onclick="close();">CLOSE</a> <br />
```

But this web page is not working:

```
<body onload="close();">
```

or

```
<head>
<script text="text/javascript">window.close;</script>
</head>
```

I figured out the reasons via Debugging:

1. Where I override the Javascript into `UIWebView` is `ShouldStartLoad...`, `didStartLoad..`, `didFinishLoad...`.
2. When in `didStartLoad`, it seems that `onload` event is running before overriding Javascript into `UIWebView`.
3. I override the Javascript late. `performSelector: withObject:afterDelay: delayTime`
4. Some webView is working but some webView is not working.

Are there some solutions?

Comment: I cannot edit the web code.. can olny edit my app code.